# Pagination with Wordpress using "wp-query"

Tags: php, post, pagination, wordpress

Hey all i'm running a query loop in a custom `page.php` using a custom post type. I would for it to paginated so i could have a specific amount of post per page. I was wondering if someone could help me out. I have added my code below:

```
<?php query_posts( array(
     'post_type' => array( 'POSTTYPE' ),
      'showposts' => -1 )
     ); ?>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


         <div class="">
         <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
         <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' , array('class' => 'aligncenter project_post_thumbnail') ); ?> 
         <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">View </a>
         </div>


<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as [wordpress.org documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Pagination) says:

> Pagination won't work correctly, unless you set the 'paged' query var appropriately: adding the paged parameter

Example of usage:

```
<?php
 $args = array(
               'cat' => '5',
               'post_type' => 'POSTTYPE',
               'posts_per_page' => 6,
               'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1),
               );

query_posts($args);
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
 /* Do whatever you want to do for every page... */
?>
     <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
     <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' , array('class' => 'aligncenter project_post_thumbnail') ); ?> 
     <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">View </a>
<?php
    endwhile;
?>
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous') ?></div>
    <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('More &raquo;') ?></div>
</div>
<?php
    wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data
?>
```

Also you can check [rvoodoo guide](http://www.rvoodoo.com/projects/wordpress/wordpress-tip-fixing-pagination-on-custom-queries-with-query_posts/) if you have more questions about it.

Comment: Hello Mitogh it did not work nothing is showing up from my post type. i have double and triple checked that the custom post type name is correct. and what do you mean here:                    
 /* Do whatever you want to do for every page... */

Comment: i just searched an 'cat' is category and i do not have any categories setup for that custom post type. so i just deleted that part. THANKS again Mitogh i appreciate it.